# File read(i.e. using vfs_read()) from LKM init_module()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, linux-mint

I would like to read files from my LKM "initialization" function so that I can config the LKM from some configuration files.

I'm wondering if it is not a good practice to read files even from the initialization function of LKM; I heard that it is NOT recommended to read files from LKM after all kernel was initialized.

Please advice me.
Thank you.

Daum

Comment: It is definitely [not a good idea](http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/WhyWritingFilesFromKernelIsBad) to read files from the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from/writing to files from the kernel is definitely not recommended.

The [Kernel Newbies wiki page](http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/WhyWritingFilesFromKernelIsBad) describes it quite nicely.

> For several reasons:
>
> - Selecting where and in what format to read/write data is a policy and    policy does not belong to kernel. A userland daemon is much
>     easier to    replace with one that receives or sends the data over a
>     network,    generates or converts them from/to different format etc.
> - Filesystem operations need a user context (i.e.: current != NULL).    You can't be sure you're in user context so you can't write something 
>     from (for example) an interrupt handler.
> - The kernel allows multiple filesystem namespaces for user processes.    Which one should it use? How do you make sure it indeed
>     uses the one    you want?
> - Kernel should not depend on particular layout of a filesystem nor on    availability of writable filesystem. The location of the file is
>     a    policy decision and policy decisions should be done in userspace.
>     Maybe you want to dump the kernel output in a remote MySQL server
>     tomorrow, that kind of policy is so much easier in userland.
> - Kernel code should be kept simple and stupid, because any bug in it    is likely to have serious consequences. Working with files requires
>     being aware of various locking issues and would add unnecessary
>     complexity.

If you want to configure the behaviour of the kernel module you're writing, you can pass module parameters that configure it on start up. Alternatively, your module can expose interfaces to [sysfs](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt) that can be used to configure it at run time.

Comment: >>If you want to configure the behaviour of the kernel module you're writing, you can pass module parameters that configure it on start up.
[Happy] How I can pass module parameters on start up? Please advice me.